# Dual boot and Installing Ubuntu On F drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, lubuntu

Currently I have two hard disks ,

a. Local Disk C (where Windows is installed)
b. Linux F ( where I want to install Linux)

[Images of Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8RbN.png)
From what I have researched, people are doing windows partitioning if they are going to use Linux on the same hard drive. So I assume I don't have to do windows partitioning if I am going to use the whole F Drive for Linux. Please correct me if I am wrong.

So what I did was to go to bios and boot from the USB and install Linux Ubuntu and I followed the installation steps but I came to a halt at Installation Type . I choose the option of 'something else' then there was a drop down but I can't tell which is the F drive.

[Linux Installation Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8jPQ.jpg)

Please Kindly advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Your machine doesn't use drive letters, that's something from left over from CP/M days (which was copied by microsoft DOS and is unique to windows).  Your drives are have make/models, and then are read by your machine hardware have have port IDs (and like technical details [nvm..]) that gets hidden by the letters of dos/windows. I boot into windows & look at which actual drive you're talking about; then install to that drive (and by drive I don't mean the letter used by users, the actual drive/device/port/..)

Comment: Your two screen shots do not seem to be from same systems? Are those yours or examples? Post this in question above  to retain formatting: `sudo parted -l` What version of Windows and is it UEFI or BIOS? You must install Ubuntu in same UEFI or BIOS boot mode. And how you boot install media, is then how it installs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution to it

1. I created a partition on my F disk by clicking on shrink disk and allocated around 100GB by going to Disk Management On Windows
2. Then I proceeded by Booting through My USB and went to linux installation.
3. Proceeded with Normal installation of Linux.
4. When it came to installation type, I choose 'Something else'.
5. I choose my 100GB of free space. I allocated some space for swap area, root and home.
6. For installation boot I choose /dev/sda
7. Installation proceeded  as Normal.